# Create strongly typed dataset from xml file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

How do you create a strongly typed dataset (in Visual Studio 2012) from a sample XML file?. The purpose is that at run-time, the dataset can be filled from XML as follows:

```
MyDataSet.ReadXml(StringXmlFileName );
```

Comment: You just want to create a DataSet from XML?http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil  First, thank you. I thought I have to have (in my Visual Studio Solution) a strongly typed dataset before I can load it from XML. The article you referenced seem to show that I can do it without strongly typed dataset. I will try it.

Comment: if have the schema file [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wha85tzb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RadioSpace  thank you. I will follow the link.